# How to make load balancing broker more fully asynchronous?

Tags: c++, c, asynchronous, zeromq

After reading through the [ZMQ manual](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all) about the [load balancing broker](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/C%2B%2B/lbbroker.cpp), I thought that it would be great to implement in my own code. So I did, adding some additional touches to make it more responsive. One performance enhancement I was looking to add was the ability to dispatch to multiple long-running work jobs concurrently. I think I'm right about this, I could be wrong though, so consider the following with respect to just the lbbroker code that's in the manual:

Two workers (clients) simultaneously request work, each with long running jobs given to them (by a manager, or manager). In the current code, It's good because it's not round-robin-ing the work to different recipients, it's selecting FCFS. But there's also a problem in that a reply is first needed from the first worker who gets through before work can be dispensed to the second worker.

Basically, I want to dole worker out as fast as there are workers ready to receive it, FCFS style and concurrently as well. At the same time, I don't want to lose the model that I have where manager A gets through to worker B, and worker B's reply *gets back* to manager A. Keeping this, which is facilitated by the request-reply pattern, while at the same time allowing worker B to receive the only manager's second work job *while A may still be processing it's job* is very desired.

How can I most easily go about achieving this? Preferably by modifying my current lbbroker implementation, which isn't too different from lbbroker in the manual.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, my difficulties stemmed from an unsufficiently specific understanding of the load balancing broker example; it is not a broker that has REP sockets in order that it must receive between each work request/worker request. So the asynchronous issue does not exist at all.

Basically, a Router has an identity message and in forwarding that along in a consistent manner, you can avoid the issue entirely, and the router is free to connect other manager worker pairs while N concurrent workers work.